# ImageIO Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, zlib, javax.imageio

I have the following code for looping through file in a directory and resizing them to 64x64 pixels.

```
for(File file: friedFiles){
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        Image resize = image.getScaledInstance(64,64, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        File resizedFile = new File(path + "\\" + file.getName());

        ImageIO.write(convertToBufferedImage(resize), "png", resizedFile);
    }
    System.out.println("Files finished");
```

This works fine but after around the 300th image in this directory it breaks, the error it gives is "Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" on the line

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

I am unsure what is causing this as the file it is trying to read is a valid image file.

EDIT: Please see the answer I added to this question the issue was a corrupted file header in the original file.

Comment: Move that file away and run again. It's possible file can be opened by viewer but not opened by ImageIO.

Comment: @BorLaze that seems to have fixed it, what would cause this to be the case about the image?

Comment: first we should to understand - problem is with file or with something else.

Comment: @BorLaze moving the file away allowed it to continue so, i am assuming its something to do with that specific file

Comment: Probably the file is truncated (missing parts of file) or contains corrupted data. A quick test is trying to open the image in another tool. Does it open at all? Do you get error messages or warnings? For further details, you need to share the file causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a corrupted file header, I was able to fix this problem by regenerating the original file and adding a try catch block to catch an `EOFException` so that in any future files it can output an error on that specific file and carry on to parse the rest of directory of files.